# What is a limitation of using DMA transfer for slow periodic data?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

I'm trying to find out about limitations for using DMA. 
I did some reaserch and found the following:

> Limitation of DMA
>
> CPU puts all its lines at high impedance state so that the DMA controller can then transfer data directly between device and memory without CPU intervention. Clearly, it is more suitable for device with high data transfer rates like a disk.
>   Over a serial interface, data is transferred one bit at a time which makes it slow to use DMA.

Is that correct? Do you need any further information for discussion?